# Is it possible for VariantClear to crash software if VariantInit is not called beforehand?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, variant

I have an exception that I cannot easily replicate, but I have a very strong suspicion that it happens during `VariantClear()`.

I have a function that defines a variant and then passes it off to another variant without calling `VariantInit()` on it first. The called function then calls `VariantClear()` on this variant, which is the likely source of the exception.

```
void Func1()
{
  VARIANT vData;
  //VariantInit(&vData); // no variant clear was done. Will adding this line stop the crash below?
  Func2(vData);
}

void Func2(VARIANT& vData)
{
  // some code here
  VariantClear(&vData); <-- this line crashes, why??
  // some code here
}
```

Can anyone explain why `VariantClear()` could be throwing an exception? Will calling `VariantInit()` in `Func1()` stop this exception from happening?

Comment: You don't have to guess, it's spelled out explicitly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-variantclear#remarks): "*Do not use VariantClear on uninitialized variants*".

Comment: If you use `_variant_t` instead of raw variants this is all handled for you.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks but the documentation doesn't explain why and I need to understand that part, not simply don't do it.

Comment: @Farhät [Do you though](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060109-27/?p=32723)? "*It is important to understand the distinction between what is a documented and supported feature and what is an implementation detail. Documented and supported features are contracts between Windows and your program. Windows will uphold its end of the contract for as long as that feature exists. Implementation details, on the other hand, are ephemeral; they can change at any time, be it at the next major operating system release, at the next service pack, even with the next security hotfix.*"...

Comment: "*... If your program relies on implementation details, you’re contributing to the compatibility cruft that Windows carries around from release to release.*"

Comment: @Farhät if the documentation says _"do not do something"_ and you want to understand the exact reason, you need to disassemble that part of Windows or step into the Windows assembly code with your debugger.

Comment: @Farhät ...The most obvious reason here is probably that `VariantClear` does different things based on the content of the `vt` field, and if t`vt` falls not within one of the known values, the function returns an error. However if by chance `vt` _is_ one of the known values,  but the rest of the structure is garbage Windows will assume that this garbage is valid data and then might do something bad leading to a crash or whatever other undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Farhät *Undefined behavior* is, well, undefined. Calling `VariantClear()` on an *uninitialized* variant is undefined behavior. Period. You don't need to understand why it fails, just that it does fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`VariantClear` checks the first 16 bits of the `VARIANT` to find the variant type.

Depending on the type, `VariantClear` might call `CoTaskMemFree` or treat the variant as a COM pointer it calls `Release` on. If the type is invalid you might crash or free some unrelated memory.

If the type is `VT_EMPTY`, `VT_NULL` or a number type it just sets all fields to zero.

If you don't initialize the `VARIANT`, the type is undefined, it could be any value left in memory from a previous operation. Therefore you must call `VariantInit` first on the `VARIANT`.

Comment: Not that should matter but in older versions of Windows VariantInit just sets the first 16 bits to zero. Newer versions sets the entire struct to zero.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you so much!